# Is there a functon in Blender to align vertex as a curve?

Tags: vertices, geometry

Within Blender, is there any way to take a series of vertex and to automatically align them into a neat curve?

For example, taking the nodes in the cutout section of this image and forming them into a curve between the two straight edges. similarly to the very crudely drawn blue line?

For preference using native features or free add ons.

[image]

Comment: Check out Mira Tools, it can do something like this. Or you could create your curve and convert it to mesh when you're happy with the curve.